# React linting definition for rule display-name not found

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In my React project, I have an *.eslintrc.json* that includes these [rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/):

```
...
  "rules": {
    "react/display-name": 1,
    "no-console": 1
  },
...
```

Sometimes instead of linting via my `npm run lint` command from package.json, I want to just check for one rule, so I run:

```
eslint --no-eslintrc --rule "no-console:2" --parser "babel-eslint" C:/src/**/*.{js,jsx}\
```

That works fine. However, it does not work for the `react/display-name` rule:

```
eslint --no-eslintrc --rule "react/display-name:2" --parser "babel-eslint" C:/src/**/*.{js,jsx}\
```

For that, I get:

```
1:1  error  Definition for rule 'react/display-name' was not found  react/display-name
```

Why is the definition not found for `react/display-name`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the rule `react/display-name` depends on the plugins section of your eslintrc.

Adding `--plugin "react"` should solve the problem

Comment: i.e., I added --plugin "react" to my command and voila!

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help